# Vue: is multiple Vue apps for a single website okay?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Hugo static website that I am making dynamic using Vue. We are transitioning. The long term plan is not yet confirmed but in the intermediate stage we are using Vue.

I already have a Vue app on one page and now I need to implement another page using Vue. So I am thinking that I will make another Vue app for that. Is this acceptable practice or is it against the recommended practice?

First vue app is for submitting a form.
Second is for getting and displaying a list of items.

Comment: You can make use of the very underrated feature of vue: Multi Page App (as opposed to Single Page App) which will generate an output for each page you configure to render that you can then bundle as a widget, instead of making one app for each, saves you the trouble of reconfiguring everything

Comment: That's a great question. Why opinion-based? Many questions are pretty much opinion-based and why is that wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Definitely it's acceptable practice.

Vue can be used for single-page apps, but there's nothing wrong in using it in a traditional multiple page-based application. In this context, one Vue app can be one "widget" on such a page, big or small.

The need to have one "central" component will come the moment you'll require sharing data between multiple components. You'll probably get there - but you don't need to worry about it now.

In fact, one of major advantages of Vue is the ease of use in this particular setup. You can introduce it to your codebase step by step, start with a few components, and slowly make your way towards a modern app.

GitLab is known for going through a major progressive rewrite from jQuery to Vue, have a look at their story:

- [Why we chose Vue](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/10/20/why-we-chose-vue/)
- [How we do Vue: one year later](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/11/09/gitlab-vue-one-year-later/)

Comment: thanks for clearing that up! that was what I had in my mind, as Vue is often touted as better for 'progressive' migrations, for the View layer, so that's what got me wondering. I just wasn't sure if having multiple apps like I did was in line with that.

Comment: I just forked a vue codepen with multiple vue apps on the same page https://codepen.io/jarajesh/pen/bJdpoB

Comment: It'd be tremendously helpful if you provided some code and a reference in regard to "central component... requiring sharing data between multiple components". For instance, if I have a MPA Rails 6 app with several individual vue apps/components that may need to talk to each other.

Answer (score -2):

It's definitely not considered normal practice, though it's not completely wrong either. I think you might be confusing a single page application in the sense that there is only a single page for the *entire website* rather than a single page application which *changes between multiple pages*.

If you implement a router into your Vue application you can set routes to different pages. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/routing.html

Comment: hi. thank you. I understand the concept of SPA + routing. I have done so in another project using React. but for this case, we are implementing Vue in parts, so I think routing is out of the question for now.

Comment: If all of the apps do vastly different things I don't see a problem in several vue app's living side by side under the same domain.

Comment: thanks for the explanation